# Права 777 как скачать файлы?

Tags: javascript, php

На сервере, в папке download лежит куча файлов и папок в иерархической структуре (download/2013/projects/simple/index.html). Права на все файлы и папки выставлены 777. Мне нужно скачать разом все содержимое из директории download. Как это осуществить?

Comment: Заархивировать.

Comment: ftp_connect (https://snipp.ru/php/ftp-php) либо иными способами. Циклом, архивированием и т.д.